# Decisional Diffie-Hellman assumption vs decisional bilinear Diffie-Hellman assumption

Tags: diffie-hellman, pairings, hardness-assumptions

For the Decisional Diffie-Hellman (DDH) assumption we know that:

Given $g^a$ and $g^b$ for uniformly and independently chosen $a,b \in Z_p$ the value of $g^{ab}$ looks like a random value in group $\mathbb{G}$.

For the Decisional Bilinear Diffie-Hellman (DBDH) assumption we know that:

In a group $\mathbb{G}_0$ of prime order $p$, let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ be chosen at random and $g$ be a generator of $\mathbb{G}_0$. The adversary when given $(g,g^a,g^b,g^c)$ must be able to distinguish a valid tuple $e(g,g)^{abc} \in \mathbb{G}_T$ from a random element $R \in \mathbb{G}_T$.

I cannot clearly understand the difference between both. Can someone state the difference of each and when to consider each one. I know that DBDH is used when considering pairings but I am still confused about the difference of both.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it can helps. But actually, you can win the DDH game if you are using pairings.

Suppose you are given $X = g^x$ and $Y = g^y$, you can apply $e(X,Y) = e(g,g)^{xy}$.

Given $Z$, your goal is to know if $(X,Y,Z)$ is a DDH triplet.

You can test, using useful properties of pairings, if $e(g,Z) = e(X,Y)$ and so you can distinguish from a random element.

So I think that's why we consider 3 numbers to distinguish.

You can also think about Key-exchange Diffie-Hellman and Joux "Tripartie DH" as described [in this PDF](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/845e/96c20e5a5ff3b03f4caf72c3cb817a7fa542.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

In short, Decisional Diffie-Hellman(DDH) can be considered that it is hard to calculate the logrithm, eazy to calcuate the exponantial. As your notation, even you have $g,\space g^a,\space g^b$. you cannot calcuate $a$ and $b$ easily, that's why it is hard to calculate $g^{ab}$.

But in bilinear pairing (you can treat $e(n,\space m)$ as a new rule of operation), what we know is that $e(n^e,\space m^f)$ equal to $e(n,\space m)^{ef}$ and calcuate $e(\text{element1},\space \text{element2})$. So it is possible to calculate $e(g,\space g)^{ab}$ because it is equal to $e(g^a,\space g^b)$ and we have known $g^a,\space g^b$ according to your assumption. In a similar way, we can calculate $e(g,\space g)^{bc}$ or $e(g,\space g)^{ac}$ easily. But that's all we have (don't ask why, bilinear pairing is just a definition of a new operation), no other way to calculate $e(g,\space g)^{abc}$